# 403 Forbidden when migrating Analytics Reporting API (from v3 to v4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm developing an asp.net core (1.0 LTS) application for a company. It dynamically generates reports using mainly Google Analytics, but also other APIs, and currently uses a self-signed SSL certificate.

I have a *custom Oauth2 authorization* flow which authorizes with Google **server-side** using the normal *analytics.readonly* scope, and then the user ends up calling on another method which accesses the *analytics/v3/data/ga* endpoint. The access token is sent in the authorization header.

**This is my problem:** I keep getting **403 forbidden when POSTing to the v4 batchGet endpoint instead.** My POST code looks like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet",
                new StringContent(requestBody));
```

Where **requestBody** is a string containing JSON, which looks like this:

```js
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2017-06-01",
          "endDate": "2017-06-30"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:sessions"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Since I'm getting a 403, I'm assuming the authorization is valid. If I POST without it I get the expected 401 error. The logical conclusion seems to be that my Analytics account doesn't have sufficient permissions to access the data, but I can get the exact same data using either the Request Composer, or the API explorer on [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) when building the same JSON. **In all cases I'm using the same account and the same viewId.**

Further questions I have besides "why isn't this working":

1. Is it possible to access the v4 endpoint this way, or do I have to use their Client Library?
2. Are the Google Docs really up-to-date?

*Any input / experience is much appreciated, thanks.*

Comment: Are you using a service account? and if so have you added the service account email to the GA view you need to access? Check the full response from the API and add it to your SO question. There should be a longer response.reason that will be helpful than the `403 forbidden`

Comment: I think you might be on to something. I'll admit it's quite confusing to me and I thought I understood service accounts, since through v3 I seemed to have access to everything I needed.
Put simply, I have been given access to my company's Analytics account through my own for testing. In the final product the on-site authorized user will manage multiple accounts for their clients.
I'll do some more digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is ridiculous, but in the interest of clarity I'll explain what went wrong and how this was resolved.
**Apparently, the Google Reporting API wasn't enabled.**

*Right, I know.* In Google's list of APIs, *the Reporting API isn't listed by default.* It just lists *popular APIs,* and with any careful reading, it becomes clear that **you have to search to get the right API.**

Maybe I thought "of course the Reporting API is listed under popular, so it has to be the one called Analytics API" or maybe I missed the qualification "popular" altogether.
**Either way, it's now working like a charm and I didn't have to change any of my original code.**

I think there's something to say about how Google communicates their information in general, but that's for another time. Let's just say it took quite a while before I **accidentally found the Reporting API page where I saw it wasn't enabled.** Well that was embarrassing!